# requests.exceptions.ReadTImeout not caught

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been having some issues with this piece of code, and I cannot figure out why.

When I run:

> ```
> try:
>      r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get',
>                       timeout=10,
>                       headers={'Cache-Control': 'nocache', 'Pragma': 'nocache'})
>     r.raise_for_status()
>     return r.json()
> except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError):
>      return False
> ```
>
> <sub>**NOTE**: Host changed for privacy, the actual service is way
>   more erratic/buggy.</sub>

I will occasionally get this error:

> requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='https://httpbin.org/get', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

I can't understand what has gone wrong;
I seem to be properly catching `requests.exceptions.RequestException` which is a superset/parent of `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout`..

---

**EDIT**: It seems updating requests has fixed it.

Comment: as a sidenote, why do you catch ValueError too?

Comment: Incase it can't decode the JSON data, as stated I am working with a finicky host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to have your error replicated, so far I tried code below,
but it still does catch a timeout.

```
import requests 

try:
   r = requests.get('http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=1000',
                     timeout=0.01,
                     headers={'Cache-Control': 'nocache', 'Pragma': 'nocache'})
   r.raise_for_status()
   print(r.json())
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError) as e:
    print('Error caught!') 
    print(e)
```

prints:

```
Error caught!
HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.120', port=8080): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.01)
```

Even in a minimal form your are still catching `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout`:

```
try:
    raise requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    print('Caught ReadTimeout')
```

My best guess is that your exception arises in some other part of code, but not in this example.

Comment: I tried that aswell and it worked... Maybe the issue is somewhere else in the code, I'll do some more looking.

Comment: Please accept as an answer if it suits this particular question.